# Multiplication of continued fraction

Tags: radicals, continued-fractions

I know the continued fractions for $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$:

$\sqrt2=1+\cfrac1{2+\cfrac1{2+\cfrac1{2+\cfrac1{...}}}}$

$\sqrt3=1+\cfrac1{1+\cfrac1{2+\cfrac1{1+\cfrac1{2+...}}}}$

Since $\sqrt6=\sqrt2{\sqrt3}$, the continued fractions should be able to be multiplied to form $\sqrt6$.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I doubt there's any particularly nice algorithm for this. Multiplying the best rational approximations to $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ won't produce the best approximations for $\sqrt{6}$. I'd like to be wrong about this, though.

Comment: @EthanBolker I actually am diving into doing this algebraically and it has some bizarre properties

Comment: the cf for √2 is [1;2, 2, 2, ... ].   so [1;2, 2, 2, ... ] x [1;2, 2, 2, ... ] = √2  x √2 = 2 which is a finite cf.   doesn't look easy.

Comment: Bill Gosper's algorithm? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232422/faster-arithmetic-with-finite-continued-fractions or https://perl.plover.com/classes/cftalk/INFO/gosper.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really get an answer, so I spent a solid three hours working it out, and I think I found it.

Let $\sqrt2=1+a$ and $\sqrt3=1+b$ meaning that given the continued fractions of both $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$, we have:

$a={1\over{2+a}}$ and $b={1\over{1+{1\over2+b}}}$

Therefore, given that $$\sqrt6=\sqrt2\sqrt3,$$ we obtain $$\sqrt6=(1+a)(1+b)=1+ab+a+b;$$

also given that that $ab={{2+b}\over{6+3a+2b+ab}}$

You can find that:

$\sqrt6=1+{{2+b}\over{6+3a+2b+ab}}+a+b$

This can be further compacted down, but it is presently 12:45AM where I am and I need some rest.